# How to do this sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql

Schema:

```
Student(studentid,name,age)
Course(coursename,dept)
enroll(studentid,coursename,grade)
```

I need to write sql to find student names for each age group with the maximum grade for the courses taken from the history and political science department.

My attempt so far has been

```
SELECT 
    name 
FROM 
    student 
GROUP BY age 
HAVING sid IN 
            (
                SELECT 
                    max(grade) 
                FROM 
                    enroll e,enroll e1 
                WHERE 
                    e.studentid = e1.studentid 
                AND e.coursename = (
                                    SELECT coursename FROM course 
                                    WHERE 
                                        dname like '%History%'
                                  ) 
                AND e1.coursename = (
                                    SELECT coursename FROM course 
                                    WHERE 
                                        dname like '%PoliticalScience%'
                                    )
            )
```

Comment: How do you define age group??

Comment: My guess is age group points to students of same age under one bracket hence the group by age.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the top grade using `subquery`. Try,

```
SELECT  d.*,
        f.dept,
        e.grade
FROM    student d
        INNER JOIN enroll e
            on d.studentID = e.studentID
        INNER JOIN course f
            ON e.courseName = f.courseName
        INNER JOIN
            (
                SELECT  a.age, c.dept, Max(b.grade) maxGrade
                FROM    student a
                        INNER JOIN enroll b
                            on a.studentID = b.studentID
                        INNER JOIN course c
                            ON b.courseName = c.courseName
                WHERE    c.dept IN ('history','political science')
                GROUP BY a.age, c.dept
            ) topScore
            ON  topscore.age = d.age AND
                topscore.dept = f.dept AND
                topscore.maxGrade = e.grade
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something along these lines

```
select 
    s.name 
from 
    student s, enroll e,
    (
        select 
            s.age as age, e.coursename as coursename, max(e.grade) as grade 
        from 
            student s, course c, enroll e
        where 
            s.studentid = e.studentid 
        and c.coursename = e.coursename 
        and (c.dept = 'history' or c.dept = 'political science') 
        group by s.age, e.coursename
    ) t
where 
    s.studentid = e.studentid 
and s.age = t.age 
and e.grade = t.grade 
and e.coursename = t.coursename
```